# How to align the text and images vertically by baseline?

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have text and three images to align by baseline vertically. I have used the vertical-align property to align the items by text-bottom but it still does not align correctly. [image: Vertical align problem]

Please see the screenshot where the transparent black box helps you to see the baseline issue.

```css
.container {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.ayc_cooperation {
  margin: 0 5% 0 5%;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #535353;
}

.ayc_cooperation:before {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.ayc_cooperation:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 6.5rem;
}

.ayc_cooperation_ini_logo {
  float: left;
  width: 9.6875rem;
  height: 4.5rem;
}

.ayc_cooperation_ini_logo img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.ayc_co_container {
  float: right;
  line-height: 8;
  height: 4.5rem;
}

.ayc_co_container img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.ayc_co_container img:first-child {
  width: 7.5rem;
}

.ayc_co_container img:nth-child(2) {
  width: 8rem;
}

.ayc_co_container img {
  margin-right: 2.5rem;
}

.ayc_co {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 2.5rem;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  line-height: 14px;
  vertical-align: text-bottom;
}

.ayc_de_lebe_ev_img {
  width: 8rem;
}

.ayc_de_lebe_ev_img img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.ayc_de_lebe_img {
  width: 7.5rem;
}

.ayc_de_lebe_img img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.ayc_gilead_img {
  width: 6rem;
}

.ayc_gilead_img img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="ayc_co_container">
    <div class="ayc_co_text ayc_co">
      Eine Kooperation von:
    </div>
    <div class="ayc_de_lebe_img ayc_co">
      <img src="http://presse.bist-du-chris.de/wp-content/themes/ayc_press/assets/media/img/deutsche-leberstiftung@3x.png" alt="Deutsche Leberstiftung">
    </div>
    <div class="ayc_de_lebe_ev_img ayc_co">
      <img src="http://presse.bist-du-chris.de/wp-content/themes/ayc_press/assets/media/img/deutsche-leberhilfe-e-v@3x.png" alt="Deutsche Leberhilfe e.V">
    </div>
    <div class="ayc_gilead_img ayc_co">
      <img src="http://presse.bist-du-chris.de/wp-content/themes/ayc_press/assets/media/img/gilead-sciences@3x.png" alt="Gilead Sciences GmbH">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You cannot do that because your image is a bitmap image—how would the web browser know where the baseline is?

Comment: The elements themselves are aligned, the text in the images aren't though. CSS can't magically position elements based of the text inside of an image. You need to edit your images so the text aligns across them from the bottom of the image.

Answer (score 1):

EDITED ANSWER / NEW SNIPPET:

The problem in this particular sitation is that you are not aligning text, but images, and there is some white space above the bottom border of some of the images, which is part of the image, especially in the the "Deutsche Leberstiftung" image. So actually, you either have to edit/cut the images to achieve the desired result, or use `position: relative` and according `bottom` settings on them to lift or lower them a little bit, as I did in the following snippet – maybe still not exactly aligned, but enough to give you an idea - you can change the `bottom` values:

```css
.container {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.ayc_cooperation {
  margin: 0 5% 0 5%;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #535353;
}

.ayc_cooperation:before {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.ayc_cooperation:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 6.5rem;
}

.ayc_cooperation_ini_logo {
  float: left;
  width: 9.6875rem;
  height: 4.5rem;
}

.ayc_cooperation_ini_logo img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.ayc_co_container {
  float: right;
  line-height: 8;
  height: 4.5rem;
}

.ayc_co_container img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.ayc_co_container img:first-child {
  width: 7.5rem;
}

.ayc_co_container img:nth-child(2) {
  width: 8rem;
}

.ayc_co_container img {
  margin-right: 2.5rem;
}

.ayc_co {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 2.5rem;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  line-height: 14px;
  vertical-align: text-bottom;
}

.ayc_de_lebe_ev_img {
  width: 8rem;
 position: relative;
 bottom: -2px;
}

.ayc_de_lebe_ev_img img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.ayc_de_lebe_img {
  width: 7.5rem;
 position: relative;
 bottom: -4px;
}
}

.ayc_de_lebe_img img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.ayc_gilead_img {
  width: 6rem;
 position: relative;
 bottom: 0px;
}

.ayc_gilead_img img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="ayc_co_container">
    <div class="ayc_co_text ayc_co">
      Eine Kooperation von:
    </div>
    <div class="ayc_de_lebe_img ayc_co">
      <img src="http://presse.bist-du-chris.de/wp-content/themes/ayc_press/assets/media/img/deutsche-leberstiftung@3x.png" alt="Deutsche Leberstiftung">
    </div>
    <div class="ayc_de_lebe_ev_img ayc_co">
      <img src="http://presse.bist-du-chris.de/wp-content/themes/ayc_press/assets/media/img/deutsche-leberhilfe-e-v@3x.png" alt="Deutsche Leberhilfe e.V">
    </div>
    <div class="ayc_gilead_img ayc_co">
      <img src="http://presse.bist-du-chris.de/wp-content/themes/ayc_press/assets/media/img/gilead-sciences@3x.png" alt="Gilead Sciences GmbH">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please note my edited answer, where the snippet now contains the solution I previously only described as a possibility in the text of my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I did edit the image and use the display:table implementation. For mobile viewports, I replace the table implementation with display: block.